# 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before colon?

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm new to AS3 and I'm trying to write a basic game code. So what I'm trying to do is when the enemy is at 0 hp, the output will say "you win!"
but it says "1084: Syntax error: expecting rightparen before colon" (on line 2)
here

```
{
if (enemyHP:Number = 0)
    trace("you win!");
}
```

thx

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write type of `enemyHP` in `if` statement and to do right comparison between Number variables you need to write `==` instead of `=`. So finally your code should look like:

```
{
    if (enemyHP == 0)
        trace("you win!");
}
```